# innodb corrupt tables

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Running shared hosting cpanel box with Mysql 5.5.

Restoring or packaging (using pkgacct) is giving off some serious database errors, on multiple various users

```
sum_joom954.jos_wf_profiles OK
warn [pkgacct] sum_joom954: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'sum_joom954'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] sum_joom954: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(774188 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database sum_joom954
horde.turba_objectswarn [pkgacct] horde.turba_objects: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.turba_objects OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.turba_objects: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(2761 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.turba_shareswarn [pkgacct] horde.turba_shares: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.turba_shares OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.turba_shares: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1440 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.horde_prefswarn [pkgacct] horde.horde_prefs: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.horde_prefs OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.horde_prefs: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(10240 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.kronolith_eventswarn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_events: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.kronolith_events OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_events: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1145 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.kronolith_shareswarn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_shares: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

.........
horde.kronolith_shares OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_shares: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1557 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.kronolith_shares_userswarn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_shares_users: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.kronolith_shares_users OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_shares_users: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1107 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.kronolith_storagewarn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_storage: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.kronolith_storage OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.kronolith_storage: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1123 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.mnemo_memoswarn [pkgacct] horde.mnemo_memos: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.mnemo_memos OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.mnemo_memos: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1101 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde
horde.nag_taskswarn [pkgacct] horde.nag_tasks: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

horde.nag_tasks OK
warn [pkgacct] horde.nag_tasks: mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'horde'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1548)

warn [pkgacct] horde: mysqldump failed -- database may be corrupt
(1093 bytes) warn [pkgacct] Failed to dump database horde

ERROR: Failed to dump one or more databases
```

I was told by cpanel tech:

```
It looks like a major problem with MySQL right now is that InnoDB is corrupt and was set as disabled, although several databases are using that storage engine. Have you attempted InnoDB recovery on this server?

Due to policy and liability issues, we won't be able to assist with forcing InnoDB recovery. However, the following link should be able to assist you:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

The file that will need to be edited is /etc/my.cnf
```

Can someone please explain to me in laymen terms on how to go about repairing these? I'm not sure how to dumb the databases. I need to first know which databases/tables have this issue. I'm decent with ssh so I can understand step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stop the database and backup all mysql files (/var/lib/mysql).
Second start the server run on console

```
 mysql_upgrade
```

If it's saying is already upgraded run again with force flag

```
 mysql_upgrade -f
```

Comment: How do I backup all mysql files via ssh? Please provide me commands to run. This is a cloudlinux/cpanel box.

Comment: `mkdir -p /root/backup; cp -r /var/lib/mysql /root/backup`

I don't know what paths do you have there ... so is possible to do not have /var/lib/mysql ... Please look yourself if there is the mysql base dir

Comment: Ok, thanks. Once I've backed up the mysql folder, what's next to repair the databases?

Comment: read the post ... do mysql_upgrade

Comment: I ran that and got this... http://tny.cz/1da944eb